# Cypher query to get subsets of different node labels, with relations

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Let's assume this use case;
We have few nodes (labeled Big) and each having a simple integer ID property.
Each Big node has a relation with millions of (labeled Small) nodes.
such as :

(Small)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(Big)

How can I phrase a Cypher query to represent the following in natural language:

> For each Big node in the range of ids between 4-7, get me 10 of Small nodes that belongs to it.

The supposed result would give 2 Big nodes, 20 Small nodes, and 20 Relations

The needed result would be represented by this graph:

[2 Big nodes, each with a subset of 10 of Small nodes that belongs to them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2YbM.png)

What I've tried but failed (it only shows 1 big node (id=5) along with 10 of its  related Small nodes, but doesn't show the second node (id=6):

```
MATCH (s:Small)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(b:Big)
Where 4<b.bigID<7
return b,s limit 10
```

I guess I need a more complex compound query.

Hope I could phrase my question in an understandable way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query does not work because the limit applies to the entire previous flow.

You need to use [`aggregation function collect`](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/aggregation/#aggregation-collect):

```
MATCH (s:Small)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(b:Big) Where 4<b.bigID<7
With b, 
     collect(distinct s)[..10] as smalls
return b, 
       smalls
```

Comment: execution results only 1 Big node along with 10 Small.

Comment: Show data example with this behaviour.

Comment: My bad, was different data model that I tested the query with. your query @stdob-- results as per required!

Answer (score 1):

As stdob-- says, you can't use limit here, at least not in this way, as it limits the entire result set.

While the aggregation solution will return you the right answer, you'll still pay the cost for the expansion to those millions of nodes. You need a solution that will lazily get the first ten for each.

Using APOC Procedures, you can use `apoc.cypher.run()` to effectively perform a subquery. The query will be run per-row, so if you limit the rows first, you can call this and use `LIMIT` within the subquery, and it will properly limit to 10 results per row, lazily expanding so you don't pay for an expansion to millions of nodes.

```
MATCH (b:Big)
WHERE 4 < b.bigID < 7
CALL apoc.cypher.run('
 MATCH (s:Small)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(b)
 RETURN s LIMIT 10', 
 {b:b}) YIELD value
RETURN b, value.s
```

Comment: the query execution gave an error:
"There is no procedure with the name `apoc.cypher.run` registered for this database instance. Please ensure you've spelled the procedure name correctly and that the procedure is properly deployed." .
Please note that I'm using neo4j ce 3.1.1

Comment: You'll need to install the [APOC Procedures plugin](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/releases). Version 3.1.0.4 is the latest version serving Neo4j 3.1.1 at this time. Here's the [documentation](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) of all the procedures and functions available.